FSCrawler not continuing job
I'm using FSCrawler 2.10 to crawl trough hundreds of PDF files, and with Tessarect OCR extract text from scanned documents/images.
It works, successfully configured everything, however the folder I am crawling trough becomes unavailable at some point (becomes unavailable on the server) - this happens mid-job, and crawler cannot continue because it can't find the folder anymore.
Day after, I wanted to resume the process, but it considers all files scanned already. I've went trough the logs, and noticed that fscrawler won't scan the file if the last modified date (file date) is before last scan date - even if the doc wasn't actually scanned.
--restart option does work in terms of reindexing all from the start - but I do not want to scan again hundreds of docs for hours (and besides, the same problem will occur at the end of the day), I want to continue where I left off (220/600 documents were scanned, but crawler refused to continue cos it considers them all scanned due to dates).
Can I somehow force continue? Can I somehow make crawler sync with Elasticsearch index and not last modified / last scanned date to determine which files are scanned?
Thank you for the help!

I'm afraid it's not possible as FSCrawler is built today.
One of the workaround you have is to run multiple fscrawler instances.
Let say you have 5 dirs in the root dir, you could start to crawl dir1 then dir2, ...
If one of the dir fails, you will "just" have to crawl this dir again.
But sadly no, there's no checkpoint yet on what FSCrawler have been crawling so far. And that would be a great enhancement for sure.
My goal is to release a stable 2.10 version somewhere before 2025. I'm not sure I'll be able to add such a mechanism before that.
